# Can a kubernetes pod belong to more than 1 kubernetes workload?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to figure out if two [workloads](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/) can share a [pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/) i.e. can a pod belong to more than 1 workload at the same time?

I would think so no because a pod should never have more than 1 owner if you think in terms of ownership references.

Comment: As the documentation defines the term "workload": *A workload is an application running on Kubernetes.*. It's not a specific Kubernetes resource, it's just another way of saying "an application". So if you rephrase your question, "Can two applications use the same pod?" then the answer is obviously yes.

Comment: I highly doubt so. If you think in terms of ownership, a pod should never have more than 1 ownership reference.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. You should not use same pod label-selector from two different workloads.
As far the k8s official [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/):

> Note:
> You must specify an appropriate selector and Pod template labels in a Deployment (in this case, app: nginx).
> Do not overlap labels or selectors with other controllers (including other Deployments and StatefulSets). Kubernetes doesn't stop you from overlapping, and if multiple controllers have overlapping selectors those controllers might conflict and behave unexpectedly.